# Changed build number is not shown at the environment where application was deployed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have build that is used as release pipeline written in yaml. It takes resources out of the build pipeline and deploys it to an environment.

[Build details after running update build task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTbbw.png)

Inside the build I'm runnig this task that is able to change build number.

##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$versionValue

However in the env view it shows build number in default format **#20230131.3** on **BuildName**

[Environment view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfD3q.png)

If I run this request:

```
$releaseUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project)/\_apis/build/builds/4577?api-version=7.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseUri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

I'm getting correct build number

buildNumber                  : rel-2023.1.30-4448-7a8e9f4

But why it is not shown on environment overview for a given deployment?

I tried updating manually buildNumber

```
[$updateBuildUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project)/_apis/build/builds/4595?api-version=7.0"
$body = "{
  `"buildNumber`": `"Adam1234`"
    }"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateBuildUri -Method PATCH -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Body $body][1]
```

but without any results at the environment view.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have you found a way how to solve it by any chance?

Comment: It seems to be a known issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-Number-Not-Updated-In-Environments/10220047